# How to toggle a boolean?

Tags: javascript, boolean, toggle

Is there a really easy way to toggle a boolean value in **javascript**?

So far, the best I've got outside of writing a custom function is the ternary:

```
bool = bool ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 1220, accepted):

```
bool = !bool;
```

This holds true in most languages.

Comment: really nice solution, i was using: test = (test == true)? false : true;

Comment: This need initialisation, so is there a way without initialisation. Though this would work on object attributes.

Comment: @user2846569, if you're toggling the boolean, that means that by nature the variable has already been initialized. You could expand it to `bool = !bool || true;` to have a default, I suppose.

Comment: @Jordan That causes ReferenceError

Comment: J.B wants a unary statement rather than binary statement. Perhaps it could be bool!! or !!bool. But so far i've never seen such syntax. I agree with Jordan. It is so short already.

Comment: This works well even when the value starts with `undefined`

Comment: Consider `bool = bool === true;` to map falsy values to false.

Comment: If anyone's needing this for VB.NET, it's bool = (not) bool

Comment: Wish there was shorter syntax, f.e. `bool=!`or something.

Comment: idk if this will help someone but it was my resolution after looking for "toggling booleans": `(showApples === isApple(fruit)` will return true for an apple if showApples is set true, but will also return true if showApples is false and the fruit is no apple.

Answer (score 123):

If you don't mind the boolean being converted to a number (that is either 0 or 1), you can use [the Bitwise XOR Assignment Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/06f6ta51%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). Like so:

```
bool ^= true;   //- toggle value.
```

This is especially good if you use long, descriptive boolean names, EG:

```
let inDynamicEditMode   = true;     // Value is: true (boolean)
inDynamicEditMode      ^= true;     // Value is: 0 (number)
inDynamicEditMode      ^= true;     // Value is: 1 (number)
inDynamicEditMode      ^= true;     // Value is: 0 (number)
```

This is easier for me to scan than repeating the variable in each line.

This method works in all (major) browsers (and most programming languages).

Comment: Since this recasts to an integer anyway, it can be simplified as:
`bool ^= 1`

Comment: As the value is casted to a number, you will be not able to do `bool === false` or `bool === true` anymore. It might break existing code, so be careful.

Comment: This is horrible, please don't

Answer (score 16):

Let's see this in action:

```js
var b = true;

console.log(b); // true

b = !b;
console.log(b); // false

b = !b;
console.log(b); // true
```

Anyways, [there is no shorter way than what you currently have.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13972910/2404470)

Answer (score 13):

```
bool = bool != true;
```

One of the cases.

Answer (score 5):

I was searching after a toggling method that does the same, but which "toggles" an initial value of `null` or `undefined` to `false`.

Here it is:

```
booly = !(booly != false)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I think a ES6 update will be good.

Usually we want a toggle that can handle everything without breaking our code.

We can use an initial value for `null` or `undefined` values as `false`.

```js
const boolToggler = b => !(b ?? false)

let foo
console.log('foo:', foo) // undefined

foo = boolToggler(foo)
console.log('foo:', foo) // true (assumes undefined as 'false')

foo = boolToggler(foo)
console.log('foo:', foo); // false

let fee = null
console.log('fee:', fee) // null

fee = boolToggler(fee)
console.log('fee:', fee) // true (assumes null as 'false')

let faa = true
console.log('faa:', faa) // true

faa = boolToggler(faa)
console.log('faa:', faa); // false
```

Comment: Isn't `!(b ?? false)` kind of redundant since it's being fed into the `!` operator? `null` and `undefined` are falsy anyway so the same behavior can be achieved with `!b`

Answer (score 1):

```
bool === tool ? bool : tool
```

if you want the value to hold true if `tool` (another boolean) has the same value

Answer (score 1):

In a case where you may be storing true / false as strings, such as in localStorage where the protocol flipped to multi object storage in 2009 & then flipped back to string only in 2011 - you can use JSON.parse to interpret to boolean on the fly:

```
this.sidebar = !JSON.parse(this.sidebar);
```

Comment: In case the variable has a different values for true/false like "Yes"/"No", I use `sidebar = (sidebar == trueValue) falseValue : trueValue;`

Answer (score 0):

I always liked Boolean value, but nowadays I'm using binary for both convenience and debugging. You can use de consept  `!key : ++key: --key` to toggle, and if you are in any asynchronous function or anytime an error or false true occurs, the value will leak out of 0(zero)/ 1(one) and you can trigger an alert to debug later.