# Shorthand for flipping a boolean variable

Tags: javascript, boolean, flip, shorthand

How can I flip the value of a boolean variable in javascript, without having to include the variable name twice?
So

```
foobarthings[foothing][barthing] = !foobarthings[foothing][barthing];
```

without writing `foobarthings[foothing][barthing]` twice.

Comment: That's actually quite clever. Never thought about that

Comment: Strange, considering `foo++` exists. Couldn't there be `foo!!` or something?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no shorter way than what you currently have.

Comment: that's not entirely true, there is such thing as the `not` operator: `ver inverse = return !foo;` that's completely valid

Comment: @JacobSchneider The code you posted isn't syntactically valid and the OP already demonstrates knowledge of the `!` operator.

Comment: Anujith Answered with `^=` operation, why do you think that's not valid?

Answer (score 13):

You can do this:

```
foo ^= 1
```

But this really switches foo between 0 and 1, not true and false.

Comment: but then you can do `(foo ^= 1) == true` (must be `==` **not** `===`)

Answer (score 3):

```
var value = true;
alert(value);
value ^= true;
alert(value);​
```

You could get 1 or 0 here

Comment: Could this be considered *short hand*?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new constructor with a boolean property and then add a prototype to flip that

```
function Bit(bit=false) {
  this._ = bit;
}
Bit.prototype.flip = function() {
  this._ = !this._;
  return this._
}

//example:
var foo = new Bit();
console.log(foo._) //logs false
foo.flip() //flips to true
console.log(foo._); //logs true
console.log(foo.flip()) //flips to false and logs it
```

Answer (score -1):

To flip the value of a boolean variable in JS you need the syntax like this:

```
return !foo;
```

It's really that easy...

Or you can do `(foo ^= 1) == true` (must be == not ===)

Comment: The question is about avoiding repeating the name when doing assignment and flipping the boolean state.

Comment: I only use the variable's name once

Comment: The user want's to assign the flipped value back to the same variable name, which this answer does not cover.

Answer (score -3):

You can have just foo and !foo in the place where you execute it or check the condition.

Comment: No, I need to store the opposite value in it.