# Two events on the same button with two click

Tags: javascript, html, button

I need to create a button that works like this :

```
var i = true

first click --> var i = false
second click --> var i = true
....
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" value="test" onclick="stop(); start();" />
```

How can i specify theese functions in my JS document ?

Comment: [Toggle a boolean in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604409/toggle-a-boolean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<input type="button" value="test" />
```

And the javascript code.

```
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var i = true;

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (i == true)
        i = false;
    else
        i = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can toggle a boolean by doing this :

```
var b = true;
b = !b
```

in your case use :

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="b = !b;" />
```

it's better to doing this with a function

```
var b = true;
function toggle () { b = !b; console.log(b) }
```

and in your html

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="toggle();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

make a counter for clicks

```js
var countClick= 0

if (countClick== 1) {
        //do the first click code
    }
    if (countClick== 2) {
        //do the second click code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply associate a function call on `onclick` event and then toggle the `boolean` value:

```js
var i = true;
function clicked () {
  //toggle the value
  i = !i; 
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="clicked();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that does what you want. You can have it toggle forever or just the one time like your example.

```js
var buttonClicks = 0;
var boolValue = true;
var boolValueOutput = document.getElementById("boolValue")

boolValueOutput.innerHTML = boolValue;

function onButtonClick()
{
  buttonClicks++;

  // If you want it to only work once uncomment this
  //if (buttonClicks > 2)
  //  return;
  
  boolValue = !boolValue;
  boolValueOutput.innerHTML = boolValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="onButtonClick();" />
<p id="boolValue"></p>
```